# how to set tooltip text color in flot chart?

Tags: javascript, html, flot

I am using flot chart with multi series data.i want to change the tooltip text color in Flot Chart.
I am  using this code:

```
$("#placeholder").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
 if (item) {  
     $("#tooltip").remove();
     var hoverSeries = item.series;
     var x = item.datapoint[0],
         y = item.datapoint[1];
     var strTip = x + " / " + y + " for " + item.series.label;

     var allSeries = plot.getData();
     $.each(allSeries, function(i,s){
         if (s == hoverSeries) return;   
         $.each(s.data, function(j,p){
             if (p[0] == x){
                 strTip += "</br>" + p[0] + " / " + p[1] + " for " + s.label;
             }
         });             
     });
     showTooltip(item.pageX, item.pageY, strTip);
  }
});
```

any one for color taking in tooltip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flot chart supports HTML tags in ToolTip

You can easily use html tag:`<span>`

Flot chart ToolTip Easily support HTML tags.

With `<span>` tag you can use `s.clor` with style.
Like this js.

```
$("#placeholder").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
 if (item) {  
     $("#tooltip").remove();
     var hoverSeries = item.series;
     var x = item.datapoint[0],
         y = item.datapoint[1];
     var strTip = "<span style=\"color:" + item.series.color + ";\""+x + " / " + y + " for " + item.series.label + "</span>";

     var allSeries = plot.getData();
     $.each(allSeries, function(i,s){
         if (s == hoverSeries) return;   
         $.each(s.data, function(j,p){
             if (p[0] == x){
                 strTip += "</br><span style=\"color:" + s.color + ";\"" + p[0] + " / " + p[1] + " for " + s.label + "</span>";
             }
         });             
     });
     showTooltip(item.pageX, item.pageY, strTip);
  }
});
```

Here clearly, I have used `item.series.color` and `s.color` in `strTip` string of ToolTip

Answer (score 2):

Kindly, use this string instead your strTip.

```
strTip += "</br><span style=\"color:"+s.color+";\">" + p[0] + " / " + p[1] + " for " + s.label+"</span>";
```

Using this string you will get same color of Tooltip text as your data series color.
here, i have used this for 4 Data series in single flotchart.
[Four Series Tool Tip][1]